# How to define the density on a subspace of a topological one

Tags: general-topology

Assume $X$ is a topological space and $A\subseteq X$.
Then $A$ is dense in $X$ iff $\overline{A}=X$.
Now, suppose $A\subseteq B\subseteq X$.

> How can I define the density of $A$ in $B$?

As I understand it, a reasonable way to overcome this difficulty is to require $\overline{A}\cap B=B$ or $\overline{A\cap B}=B$, where we are using the closure operator of $X$.

I guess the second one is more adeguate, but it is only a feeling.

Comment: Note that $A\cap B = A$.

Comment: Ah, I feel so stupid... at this point is the first one the actual definition?

Comment: The second is at least not the one because it would imply that $B$ is closed.

Comment: You are absolutely right once again

Comment: It is correct that $A$ is dense in $B$ if and only if $\overline A\cap B = B$.

Comment: Thank you, but how can you say that it is the correct generalization?

Comment: If you edit as an answer, I'll upvote it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, $A$ is dense in $B$ if for any $b\in B$ and any open $U$ with $b\in U$ you can find $a\in A$ such that $a\in U\cap B$, i.e., $a\in A\cap U$.

Assume that $\overline A\cap B = B$ and let $b\in B$, $U$ open with $b\in U$. Then, since $b\in \overline A$, there exists $a\in A\cap U$.

Assume that $A$ is dense in $B$ and let $b\in B$. Then for any open $U$ with $b\in U$ we find $a\in A\cap U$. This implies $b\in \overline A$. Hence, we have $\overline A\cap B = B$.

Comment: Ok, you checked the agreement of this definition with the equivalent notions in $X$. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is dense in $B$ iff $\operatorname{cl}_B(A)=B$ so iff $\operatorname{cl}_X(A) \cap B = B$ (by the formula that relates closure in subspaces to that in the large space) iff $B \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_X(A)$. So it suffices to check the closure of $A$ in the whole space and check if it contains $B$.

It's intuitive too: $A$ is dense in $B$ iff we can "reach" all points of $B$ by points of $A$ (formalisable by nets, e.g.) and this also can be restated as $B \subseteq \operatorname{cl}_X(A)$

Comment: Ah, now I see. This is the natural way I was looking for. Thank you very much!

Comment: He just restated your statement that $A$ is dense in $B$ iff $\overline A\cap B = B$. And "this last condition also restates that same fact." I proved in my answer.

Comment: I see what you mean, but he stated explicitly why the formula holds: it was sufficient to recall the definition of subspace closure. Maybe it is trivial, but this is why everything works.

Comment: You mean "relative closure". But this has to be proved using the relative topology. That's what you have first. And I proved in my answer that the relative closure of $A$ is $\overline A\cap B$. If you knew that already, your question seems odd.

Comment: Ok, I gave you the best answer

Comment: @HennoBrandsma, can you edit your answer? The site says to me that I can't upvote if it is not edited.

Comment: @LBJFS I did some time ago; a minor edit.

Comment: @HannoBrandsma I really don't know why but if I try to upvote, I downvote of 1; if I downvote, then I downvote of 2. I'm really disappointed O.o Anyway, maybe if you copy your answer, delete this one and you answer once again with the copied text, I can upvote. It's just an attempt...I don't know what to do.

Comment: @LBJFS I don’t mind. A few reputation points, ach.